# Same CSS gives different font sizes on different domains

Tags: php, html, css, font-size

The following is happening to me:
I have a CSS with a font where I set the size in em. 
All works fine and gives me the result I want. But on the follwing conditions something strange happens:

After developping my site with PHP and HTML pages and of course a CSS stylesheet, when I move the site form a subdirectory to the directory (a level higer) the font size suddenly changes.

I also have the same problem with the folling condition: Everything works fine on domain www.abc.com but as soon as I access the site trough a site alias www.xyz.com again the font size, specified in em, differs from the other.

Is there something I need to think about in the CSS?

Regards,
Hans

Comment: Make sure your browser's zoom settings are identical, they are stored on a per-domain basis

Comment: Domains have nothing to do with font sizes, so quite possibly you have a) different zoom defaults in your browser set for each URL b) have broke the CSS links in one or the other of the sites due to moving directories around c) added CSS in one or the other of the sites due to moving directories around. But we can't really say for sure unless you can share the two URLs with us so we can look.

Comment: Check the paths to your CSS files. I'd bet that one or more are hard coded and match one domain, but not the other.

Comment: Is your file structure still the same. If you went from bobstesting and your links where bobstesting blah blah blah to bobsfishing.com at the main directory, all your code is still bobstesting which no longer exists.

Comment: Browser zoom settings are the same, links to css or others do not contain hard links. The CSS is working on both domains (the hard domain and the alias). As soon as I alter something, I see the results on both domains. It is just the font size that is smaller on the alias domain than on the other.

Answer (score 1):

After ensuring your CSS file is being accessed correctly...
Have you set a base font size? EM's are relative, so a base size needs to be set. For example in your CSS you would use:

```
html, body{font-size:14px;}

p{font-size:1em;}
h1{font-size:1.2em;}
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you asked to do but the result stays the same.
Accessing the page through the normal domain name gives me the resut I expected. Accessing the exacte same files through a domain alias gives other font sizes. I am using the same browser when accessing the websites.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! It seems what I described as my problem only happens in Chrome.
I did clear cache, cookies, history, etc. What I did not clear were passwords, site certifcates and apps hosted.

After clearing everything in my browser the site came up correctly though normal domain name and through alias domain name.

Thans for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not about the font size actually the zoom level of each domain. Check your zoom size for each domain is the same